# Different Apache log file for each subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Is it possible to configure Apache to use a different log file for each *subdomain*, even if all of the subdomains are within the same VirtualHost container?

So, I have only one VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias test1.example.com test2.example.com test3.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And I want to end up with the following log files:

```
/var/log/httpd-access_test1.log
/var/log/httpd-access_test2.log
/var/log/httpd-access_test3.log
```

I know I can probably do this with a custom log format and split-logs, but I was wondering if there's a way to just have Apache do it for me.

Answer (score 3):

You just specify `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` within each `VirtualHost` directive.  With that in mind, you would not be able to use `ServerAlias` and have separate log files for each host via normal performance without specifying separate `VirtualHost`.

However, you could pipe the log through a script, and have the script make the separate files.  Look at the piped logging documentation.

You could also use a post processing script, such as utilizing `grep` to parse out the logs.  A post processing script could be specified in the nightly logrotate under the `postrotate` or `preprotate` sections.

[Apache 2.2 Piped Logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped)

Comment: Having a different server log for each VirtualHost doesn't help me. I have only *one* VirtualHost. Within that single VirtualHost there are multiple subdomains. I need separate logs for each subdomain within the single VirtualHost.

Comment: Separate your `ServerAlias` subdomains into `VirtualHost` s with identical configurations (See the Apache documentation Re: `NameVirtualHost`), or proceed using piped logging & a custom processing script as Warner describes above.

Comment: I'd really rather not do that, the VirtualHost has *a lot* of configuration with it, and it would be a lot of copy/paste configuration stuff. Maybe there's a way I can do an Include with the generic stuff...

Comment: piped logging as Warner describe will probably be a good bed for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use apache environment variables to get this working:

```
LogFormat "%h \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhostformat

SetEnvIfNoCase Host example\.com mainlog
CustomLog /var/log/httpd-example.log vhostformat env=mainlog

SetEnvIfNoCase Host test1\.example\.com vhost1log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd-access_test1.log vhostformat env=vhost1log

SetEnvIfNoCase Host test2\.example\.com vhost2log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd-access_test2.log vhostformat env=vhost2log

SetEnvIfNoCase Host test3\.example\.com vhost3log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd-access_test3.log vhostformat env=vhost3log
```